# cURL command parameters problem, not retrying the right number of times

Tags: linux, curl, command-line

Here's my cURL command:

```
/usr/bin/curl --ipv4 --connect-timeout 1 --retry 15 --retry-delay 2 --retry-max-time 15 --no-keepalive --no-tcp-nodelay -L --silent 'http://www.example.org' -v --trace-time
```

When there's a network congestion issue, it doesn't retry the number of times specified... Here's the output I get:

```
13:29:01.884487 *   Trying 104.18.47.34... 
13:29:02.382339 * After 498ms connect time, move on! 
13:29:02.382512 * connect to 104.18.47.34 port 80 failed: Connection timed out 
13:29:02.382595 *   Trying 104.18.46.34... 
13:29:02.631165 * After 248ms connect time, move on! 
13:29:02.631287 * connect to 104.18.46.34 port 80 failed: Connection timed out 
13:29:02.631369 * Failed to connect to www.example.org port 80: Connection timed out
13:29:02.631423 * Closing connection 0
```

Any idea what is wrong with my parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my cURL version (7.58).

"Connection timed out" wasn't handled as a transient error, correctly, until version 7.67.0 (https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4461).

I upgraded cURL to the latest available version (7.68) and haven't seen this error since.